# Some options in the select only visible by super_admin

Tags: php, laravel

I would like some options in the select(for example `main_title=banner`, `main_title=law` , `main_title=faq` ) to be visible only for super_admin.

main_title.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="main_title">{{ trans('labels.main_title') }}</label>
    <select v-model="post.main_title | mainTitle" name="main_title" id="main_title" class="form-control">
        @foreach($main_title_options as $option)
            <option {{ old('main_title') == $option->value ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }} value="{{ $option->value }}">
                {{ trans('labels.'.$option->value) }}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

my PostController:

```
public function create()
{
    $time = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

    list(
        $images,
        $documents,
        $medias,
        $categories,
        $main_title_options,
        $event_type_options,
        $event_halls,
        ) = $this->repo->getPostCreateEditdata();

    $edit = false;
    \JavaScript::put(compact('tags', 'categories', 'images', 'documents', 'medias'));


    return view('posts.create-edit', compact(
        'main_title_options',
        'main_title',
        'event_halls',
        'event_type_options',
        'time',
        'edit'));
}
```

I tried something with this, but I did not succeed.

```
  @if(Auth::user()->hasRole(['super_admin']))
```

what to do here?

```
public function getPostCreateEditdata()
{
    $images = Document::whereFiletype('image')->with(['users'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(20)->get();
    $documents = Document::whereFiletype('document')->with(['users'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(20)->get();
    $medias = Document::whereFiletype('media')->with(['users'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(20)->get();

    $categories = Taxonomy::whereType('category')->get();

    $main_title_options = Settings::whereName('post_main_title_option')->get();
    $event_type_options = Settings::whereName('post_event_type_option')->get();
    $event_halls = Settings::whereName('event_hall')->get();

    //documents are lazy loaded and we load only 20 at first, so we need to include the ones from old input if any
    if (old('documents'))
        $documents = $documents->merge(Document::whereIn('id', old('documents'))->get());

    return array($images, $documents, $medias, $categories, $main_title_options, $event_type_options, $event_halls);
}
```

In advance thank you, and forgive the interference, and in the worse English.

Comment: Can you check that a user is a super admin? Like in the if statement, die dump something to check that your if statement is working. Because then you could say @if($option == 'super admin only option) then you could show that select option.

Comment: You should filter the options in `getPostCreateEditdata`

Comment: i check, statement is working, but I have no idea for the rest

Comment: done, everything works, thank you, but now I have another problem. How to block to user to write in url 'main_title=banner' and go on this page??